# In App Purchase Application crash if click on back button or on pruchase button

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

im trying to implement in app purchase to my android application
i used the Google dungeon sample to add it to my code

Now my problem
if i choose a item to purchase and then on my buy button the billing site open
but if i click on purchase button or on my back button (if i dont want to purchase)
my app crash

may anyone of you know what my problem is =( i already searched for long time to find it
the exception is called `RuntimeException on ActivityThread.handleReveiver(ActivityThread$ReveiverData)`

Comment: Could always try another Tutorial: http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/simple-inapp-billing-payment-t52060.html

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps you. When I copied the manifest entries over:

```
service android:name="BillingService" /> 

receiver android:name="BillingReceiver">
intent-filter>
action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.IN_APP_NOTIFY" />
action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE" />
action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED" />
intent-filter>
receiver>
```

I was getting your same error, I had to change the BillingService and the BillingReciever name to this:

```
service android:name = "com.epl.android.google.apis.BillingService"
```

and

```
receiver android:name="com.epl.android.google.apis.BillingReceiver"
```

Obviously the `com.epl.android.google.apis` is my "package" name, changed it to that in the manifest file, I am all good to go now!